# airflow airbyte operator - module not found

Tags: airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver, airbyte

**Context**
I'm using Airflow hosted on Google kubernetes engine, I've added `apache-airflow-providers-airbyte 3.2.0` to the requirements.txt which is installed and appears on the Airflow - Admin > Providers" UI along with the default providers.
[image]

**Blocker**
A "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.airbyte'" error appears for the following import

```
from airflow.providers.airbyte.operators.airbyte import AirbyteTriggerSyncOperator
from airflow.providers.airbyte.sensors.airbyte import AirbyteJobSensor
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing [dependency packages](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-http/stable/index.html) installed